# Создание объекта класса на статический указатель

Tags: c++, указатели

Очень странный вопрос.
Есть программа, есть там код на подобие кода ниже.. и почему то при создании второй раз объекта класса B в нем не заходит в цикл if (!p) {}.

Но если написать отдельно в отдельном проекте, все работает.
В чем могут быть ошибки? Пробовал и if(p==0) и if(p==000000)  =))))))

```
 A.h
 #pragma once
    class A {
    public:
        int a;
    };

static A * p;

B.h
#pragma once
#include "A.h"
class B {
public:
    B() {

        if (!p)
        {
            std::cout << "Pustoy ucazatel p\n";
            p = new A();
        }

    }

};


#include <iostream>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
int a = 1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    {

    B* ptr  = new B;

    delete ptr;

    delete p; p = 0;


    if (!p) std::cout << p << "\n";

    ptr = new B; // При создании второй раз объекта класса B в нем не заходит в цикл if (!p) {}

    }

    while (a == 1) {}

}
```

Comment: опечатка  if(p==0) и if(p==000000), поспешил при написании темы

Comment: https://ideone.com/t65NgP - вроде все работает? что у вас не так? И кстати - что такое "объект класса на статический указатель"? :) Да, и лучше уж вместо вечного цикла `while (a == 1) {}` напишите какой-нибудь `system("pause");` или `getch()`...

Comment: может просто не печатает строку из-за того что буфер не сбрасывается? добавь `<< std::endl`. Если не оно, то есть ли какие-то cpp файлы в реальности?

Comment: Не вы водится "Pustoy ucazatel p" когда создаешь обьект второй раз!

Comment: я понимаю что вопрос глупый если не видно среди какого кода данный код находился.... но там ничего такого нет что влияло бы на него =((( Ерунда какая-то..

Comment: @Anton так есть ли ещё какие-нить файлы, в которые включается A.h или нет? и как на самом деле устроены B.{h,cpp}? Определять статическую переменную в хедере вне класса имеет смысл только для очень специфического и сомнительного круга задач...

Comment: @Fat-Zer
Да у меня именно специфический вариант и нужно вынести указатель глобально, и удалять обьект не в деструкторе другого класса а в определенном месте..

Вроде и
#pragma once 
стоит перед объявлением указателя.....

Comment: @Anton, ты на конкретные вопросы ответь про структуру файлов.... потому что в варианте из вопроса всё работает, но если есть другие файлы, то возможно поведение сильно отличающееся от желаемого...

Comment: _Но если написать отдельно в отдельном проекте, все работает_. Я так понимаю, в вопросе вы привели тот код, который работает? А спрашиваете, почему не работает какой-то другой код, которого в вопросе нет?

Comment: наванговал ответ...

Comment: @Fat-Zer

Все разбито конечно на файлы h и cpp
'
- A.h подгружен в C.h а он в А.cpp
- B.h подгружен в C.h а он в B.cpp 
- C.h подгружен в main.cpp

при этом static указатель на объект класса А находится в B.h
'
wololo Да, поэтому вопрос "Странный"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static A * p;
```

Это **определяет** глобальную статическую переменную, которая будет локальной для каждой единицы трансляции (для каждого `*.cpp` файла). Другими словами приведённый код будет создавать по одному различному экземпляру класса `A` для каждого `.cpp` файла. Если это не ожидаемое поведение, а хочется создать обычный синглтон, то следовало бы объявить в `A.h` переменную как внешнюю:

```
extern A* aPtr;
```

А в `A.cpp` определить её как обычную глобальную:

```
A* aPtr;
```

Более разумным было бы сделать её статическим членом класса. Можно даже публичным:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
    static A * aPtr;
};
```

но лучше сделать его приватным и инкапсулировать полноценный интерфейс в `A`:

```
class A {
    int a;
    static A * aPtr;
public:
    static A* instance () { return aPtr; }
    static void createInstance () { aPtr=new A; }
    static void destroyInstance () { delete aPtr; }
};
```

Интерфейс показан для примера и абсурдно избыточен.

Определить `A::aPtr` в `cpp` файле всё равно необходимо.

Comment: Extern пробовал

Linker Tools Error LNK2019 выдает

Comment: @Anton, **определить** её в одном и только одном `*.cpp` файле при этом не забыл?

Comment: Ты просто мегамозг..... заработало, но честно признаться до конца не понимаю...
в  В.h файле написал extern A* aPtr;
а в В.cpp файле  A* aPtr;
и заработало
Да еще и в C.cpp файле куда подгружен  В.h  - там удаляется по aPtr и зануляется.

Comment: не знаю, как объянить ещё... надо чётко понимать разницу между *определением* и *объявлением*. Изначальный вариант именно определял статическую переменную в хедере, что, я повторюсь, может пригодиться только для очень странных целей. `extern` объявляет внешнюю глобальную переменную, но её при этом обязательно где-то определить иначе линкер не будет знать куда её приткнуть... ЗЫ: если вопрос решён не забудь отметить решённым, чтобы тема не болталась.

Comment: Я забыл определить ее вне класса.... когда со статика на экстерн переделал.... 
А разницу я понимаю)